# WordPress ACF conditional logic for taxonomy fields

Tags: wordpress, custom-post-type, advanced-custom-fields, custom-taxonomy

I currently have a `custom taxonomy` select field called "Location" and another custom taxonomy called "Company". What I would want to do is to `hide/show` the Company check-boxes based on the chosen Location in the select box. This is for the back-end.

The Person `custom post type` is associated with a Company and each Company is associated with a Location taxonomy. `Advanced Custom Fields` conditional logic does not extend to taxonomy fields and if anybody knows a way to go around this limitation that would be super awesome.

Comment: I'm in doubt that this is genrally possible with the acf-framework.

Answer (score 0):

I am looking for taxonomy-related conditional logic as well and I found a post on the ACF support forums (http://support.advancedcustomfields.com/forums/topic/conditional-logic-using-taxonomy-field/) that shows many other people looking for this as well.  However, there was no solution or answer in this post (most recent post asking for help being 6/7/16).  Perhaps it will be solved in the future given the many requests, but no answers there at present.

Seems that the best option for now is to use jQuery on the backend.

Comment: External references are not preferred answers as they could potentially be removed in the future. Please consider adding key points in your answer post.

Comment: @Coderchu I've updated the answer to clarify the purpose of the external link, which is to just show the number of others also seeking a solution and that there's no current ACF-based option.  I hope this helps.